# Autolayout center x alignment resulting in infinite layout loop on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, autolayout

Our app is hanging on the iPhone 6 Plus only.  The app becomes stuck in an infinite layout loop.  We have found we can stop the layout loop by removing autolayout constraints that use "center x alignment" and "center y alignment".

Can anyone provide insight into why this is happening?

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x3658bf4e in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x29af3962 in __44-[NSISEngine fixupIntegralizationViolations]_block_invoke_2 ()
#2  0x29aebd88 in -[NSISLinearExpression enumerateVariablesAndCoefficients:] ()
#3  0x29aedbc8 in __44-[NSISEngine fixupIntegralizationViolations]_block_invoke ()
#4  0x29ae8de8 in -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] ()
#5  0x29aed8fc in -[NSISEngine fixupIntegralizationViolations] ()
#6  0x29aed310 in -[NSISEngine optimize] ()
#7  0x29af32e2 in -[NSISEngine constraintDidChangeSuchThatMarker:shouldBeReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:] ()
#8  0x29af315c in -[NSISEngine tryToChangeConstraintSuchThatMarker:isReplacedByMarkerPlusDelta:undoHandler:] ()
#9  0x29ae83fa in -[NSLayoutConstraint _tryToChangeContainerGeometryWithUndoHandler:] ()
#10 0x29ae7f98 in -[NSLayoutConstraint _setSymbolicConstant:constant:] ()
#11 0x2c3ef516 in -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _autoresizingConstraints_frameDidChange] ()
#12 0x2c2f8b3c in -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] ()
#13 0x2c31833c in -[UIScrollView setFrame:] ()
#14 0x2c8f03da in -[_UIQueuingScrollView setFrame:] ()
#15 0x2c8f0168 in -[_UIQueuingScrollView _setFrameAndApplyPageSpacing:] ()
#16 0x2c8755b4 in -[_UIPageViewControllerContentView layoutSubviews] ()
#17 0x2c2fbb36 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#18 0x2bd23ccc in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#19 0x2bd1f6b4 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#20 0x2bd1f53c in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#21 0x2bd1ef20 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#22 0x2bd1ed24 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#23 0x2c2f3fc4 in _afterCACommitHandler ()
#24 0x28e275cc in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#25 0x28e24c8a in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#26 0x28e25092 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#27 0x28d73620 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#28 0x28d73432 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#29 0x300db0a8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#30 0x2c35d808 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We were compiling our app with XCode 5 moving to XCode 6 seems to have resolved this issue.